# Sequelize multiple joins for fetching data

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a CRUD application with Sequelize and ExpressJS that has the following tables:

| Parents | Students | ParentStudents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| name | name | idParent |
|  |  | idStudent |

I want to query the **Parents** table and have students key created by a left join between students and **ParentStudents** on **idParent**;

I want to get data in the following way:

```json
{
  "data":[
    {
      "name":"nameParent2",
      "students":[
        {
          "name":"Student1"
        },
        {
          "name":"Student2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"nameParent2",
      "students":[
        {
          "name":"Student1"
        },
        {
          "name":"Student2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried something like this, but is wrong and giving data from ParentStudents:

```js
models.parents.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.parentStudents
    }]
}).then(data => {
    res.json({
        message: "Hello from server!!!",
        data: data
    });
});
```

Like this is failing to make the association between Students and ParentStudents. (*students is not associated to parentStudents!*)

```js
models.parents.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.parentStudents,
        include: [{
            model: models.students
        }]
    }]
}).then(data => {
    res.json({
        message: "Hello from server!!!",
        data: data
    });
});
```

My relationships are done like this:

```js
db.parents.hasMany(db.parentStudents);
db.students.hasMany(db.parentStudents);
```

I also tried Many-to-Many, but still doesn't work:

```js
db.students.belongsToMany(db.parents, { through: db.parentStudents });
db.parents.belongsToMany(db.students, { through: db.parentStudents });
```

Does someone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is:

```js
let parents = await models.parents.findAll();

for (let parent of parents) {
  let idParent = parent.dataValues.id;
  let students = await models.sequelize.query(`
    SELECT * FROM students s
    LEFT JOIN parentStudents ps
    ON s.id = ps.studentId 
    WHERE ps.parentId =${idParent};
  `);

  parent.dataValues['students'] = students;
}
```